# "depend on" in relative clause

Tags: grammar, relative-clauses

Collins Cobuild English Grammar says

> "If the verb in a relative clause is a phrasal verb ending with a preposition, you cannot move the preposition to the beginning of the clause."

Macmillan says "depend on" is a phrasal verb.

So is "I’m looking for an assistant **on whom** I can **depend**" wrong?

Comment: [Here](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/10744/4559) is a thorough answer about phrasal verbs that I recommende reading.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing grammatically wrong with:

*I’m looking for an assistant on whom I can depend.*

it is equivalent to:

*I’m looking for an assistant I can depend upon.*

or

*I’m looking for an assistant I can depend on.*

The "dangling preposition" is not a grammar violation, but it may not meet some editor's style standards.

Comment: These two options sound natural to my (American) ear:
 - "I'm looking for an assistant I can depend on."
 - "I'm looking for a dependable assistant."

The other two options are grammatically correct, but do not sound natural to me.  "Whom" and "upon" are not used much anymore:
 - I'm looking for an assistant on whom I can depend.
 - I'm looking for an assistant I can depend upon.

Comment: I agree with you. *"I'm looking for a dependable assistant."* sounds best to me.