# Is "up" in phrase "cut up" required or optional? If "up" is required, what is the difference between "cut up" and "cut"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I read the definition of ground beef on Cambridge just now

> meat, usually beef, that has been cut up into very small pieces, often using a special machine

Then I realized that there are lots of verbs followed by "up", such as "cut up", "wash up".

Is "up" in this kind of phrases required or optional?

It seems that getting rid of up does affect the meaning at all,
for example

> ground beef is a kind of beef that has been cut into very small pieces.

Note: this post is NOT about general phrasal verb, such as stand up, turn up.

If "cut up" and "cut" have different meaning, please explain in detail, some other combination like "stand up", "wake up", cannot help me distinguish "cut up" and "cut".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When to add "up" after a verb and when not?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/10725/when-to-add-up-after-a-verb-and-when-not)

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Thanks for comment, would please point out a location approximately that matches my OP, I've went through such a long piece to dig in phrasal verb, which is NOT I am asking.

Comment: Related: https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/115522/36187

Comment: Well, they _are_ phrasal verbs. _Cut up_ means _divide into pieces_. _Wash up_ has different meanings in American and British English, but both are distinct from _wash_.

Comment: @KateBunting So, "... has been cut up into" and "has been cut into" have different meaning, right?

Comment: In your example, which goes on to mention 'very small pieces', no. But in general, if you cut something you make a cut in it, and if you cut it up you divide it into pieces.

Comment: @KateBunting Thanks a lot! Please move your comments to answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding *up* to a verb sometimes changes the meaning, but not always. (*Stand* can mean *rise to one's feet* as in *stand up*, or *be in a standing position.*)

In general, to *cut* something is to make a cut in it, to *cut it up* is to divide it into pieces. However, as your example goes on to mention *very small pieces*, you could omit the *up* without changing the meaning.